# Stop ssh from breaking out of while loop

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

```
if [[ $1 = "-r" ]]; then
   RECONNECT=true
fi

while true;
do
   ssh -x user@host;

   if [[ $RECONNECT = false ]]; then
      exit
   fi
done
```

Is there anyway I can make ssh reconnect? It erconnects when I type 'exit' in the shell I'm logged into, but not if I get disconnected from the remote computer. Can't use the -n switch to ssh, because it needs to read the stdin.

Comment: Check if your script resumes at all: add an `echo Reconnecting` line immediately after the call to `ssh`. It's possible that although you've been disconnected from the remote computer, the `ssh` process itself hasn't yet exited. If that's the case, typing Control-C to interrupt `ssh` should allow your script to continue.

Comment: What is the default value of RECONNECT? You don't show that here. You might want to use `[[ $RECONNECT == "true" ]] || exit`

Comment: Do you have `set -e` or `set -o errexit` somewhere in your script before this snippet? This would cause your script to exit if an error occurs, for example if `ssh` returns with an exit code unequal 0.

Comment: @Adaephon you are so right. Thank you! I got so used to having the 'set -e' along with the hashbang that it didn't even cross my mind.

Comment: @ni9e You could always use `ssh -x user@host || true` if you want to keep `set -e`